# How to build the heliocentric algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given this problem:

> Consider two of the planets in the orbital system: Earth and Mars.
>   Assume the Earth orbits the Sun in exactly 365 Earth days, and Mars
>   orbits the Sun in exactly 687 Earth days. Thus the Earth’s orbit
>   starts at day 0 and continues to day 364, and then starts over at day
>   0. Mars orbits similarly, but on a 687-day time scale.
>
> We would like to find out how long it will take until both planets are
>   on day. 0 of their orbits simultaneously. Write a program that can
>   determine this.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> The first line of input contains an integer N indicating the number of
>   test cases. N lines follow. Each test case contains two integers E and
>   M. These indicate which days Earth and Mars are at their respective
>   orbits.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> For each case, display the case number followed by the smallest number
>   of days until the two planets will both be on day 0 of their orbits.
>   Follow the format of the sample output.
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>
> 0 0
>
> 364 686
>
> 360 682
>
> 0 1
>
> 1 0
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>
> Case 1: 0
>
> Case 2: 1
>
> Case 3: 5
>
> Case 4: 239075
>
> Case 5: 11679

I tried solving the problem using modules but it doesn't seem correct

```
static string readInput;
static string firstStr = "";
static string secondStr = "";
static int firstInput;
static int secondInput;
static int testCases = 10;
static int caseNumber = 1;
static int outPut;
caseNumber <= testCases

static void Main(string[] args) {
  //recall runProcess as long caseNumber is less or equal testCases
  while (caseNumber <= testCases) {
    runProcess();
    Console.WriteLine("Case " + caseNumber + ": " + outPut);
    caseNumber++;
  }
}
```

Read input from console:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main process, is extracted to void so we can recall it.
/// </summary>
public static void runProcess() {
  readInput = Console.ReadLine();
  if (readInput != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < readInput.Length; i++) {
      secondStr = secondStr + readInput[i];
      if (readInput[i] == ' ') {
        firstStr = secondStr;
        secondStr = "";
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  firstInput = Convert.ToInt32(firstStr);
  secondInput = Convert.ToInt32(secondStr);
  outPut = atZero(firstInput, secondInput);
}

/// <summary>
/// This method takes the input data from the console to later determine the zero point
/// </summary>
/// <param name="earthDays"></param>
/// <param name="marsDays"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int atZero(int earthDays, int marsDays) {
  int earthOrbit = 365;
  int marsOrbit = 687;
  int modEarth = earthOrbit;
  int modMars = marsOrbit;
  int earthDistinction = earthOrbit - earthDays;
  int marsDistinction = marsOrbit - marsDays;
  if ((modInverse(earthDistinction, marsDistinction, modMars)) == 0) {
    return (modInverse(marsDistinction, earthDistinction, modEarth)) * marsDistinction;
  } else {
    return (modInverse(earthDistinction, marsDistinction, modMars)) * earthDistinction;
  }
}
```

mod invert

```
/// <summary>
/// The method below takes a denominator, numerator and a mod to later invert the mod.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="denominator"></param>
/// <param name="numerator"></param>
/// <param name="mod"></param>
/// <returns>modInverse</returns>
static int modInverse(int denominator, int numerator, int mod) {
  int i = mod, outputAll = 0, d = numerator;
  while (denominator > 0) {
    int divided = i / denominator, x = denominator;
    denominator = i % x;
    i = x;
    x = d;
    d = outputAll - divided * x;
    outputAll = x;
  }
  outputAll %= mod;
  if (outputAll < 0) outputAll = (outputAll + mod) % mod;
  return outputAll;
}
```

Is there any way to solve the problem without modules?

Thanks.

Comment: you're looking for the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of 365 and 687.

Comment: How would that help determining when they both are at 0?

Comment: If they both start at 0, after "least common multiple" number of days they are both the first time back again at 0 simultanously. Earth is at 0 at every n*365 days, Mars at every m*687 days. They are both at 0 at the same time when n*365=m*687, and the first time that happens is at the lcm.

Comment: Note that in the wiki article I linked above, there Is a section about planetary alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward way to calculate a solution could be this method:

```
private static int DaysTillBothAt0(int currentEarthDay, int currentMarsDay)
{
    int result = 0, earth = currentEarthDay, mars = currentMarsDay;
    while (earth != 0 || mars != 0)
    {
        result += 1;
        earth = (earth + 1) % 365;
        mars = (mars + 1) % 687;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is of course not the fastest alogrithm or mathematically extraordinary elegant, but for the required data range performance doesn't matter here at all. (I don't know what your teacher expects, though).

It simply counts the orbits forward until they meet at `0`.

You can use this for your test cases like this:

```
result = DaysTillBothAt0(0, 0); // 0
result = DaysTillBothAt0(364, 686); // 1
result = DaysTillBothAt0(360, 682); // 5
result = DaysTillBothAt0(0, 1); // 239075
result = DaysTillBothAt0(1, 0); // 11679
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution for this problem

```
private static int DaysTillBothAt0(int currentEarthday, int currentMarsday) {
 int count = 365 - currentEarthday;
 currentMarsday = (currentMarsday + count) % 687;
 while (currentMarsday != 0) {
     currentMarsday = (currentMarsday + 365) % 687;
     count += 365;
}
return currentMarsday;
}
```

Comment: What if you a) created names for 365 & 687 b) exchanged their roles?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).